# Show PDF directly from byte array without saving into Hard Disk in c#

Tags: pdf-viewer

I'm trying to show a PDF directly from byte array without saving into Hard Disk n c#. Is   there any component(pdf viewer) which doesn't need a "file" as input?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just didn't expect this much attention :D

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used [XtremeDocumentStudio.NETFree](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XtremeDocumentStudio.NETFree/) and it's working well.

```
documentViewer1.LoadDocument(mtStream, "");
```